# Spring Integration Delayer- messages retained in the persistent message store

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Below is the delayer code which I am using in my application. The output channel checkMessageInProgress is a database stored procedure call which will check if the message needs to be processed or delayed. If the message needs to be delayed again, the retry count is incremented. After 3 delays, custom Application Exception is raised. I am using a jdbc Message Store for the delayer messages.

The below code is working fine with delaying the messages. I see huge number of messages getting delayed by the delayer and at times I am observing messages are not getting deleted  from the message store(Message table) although the message is successfully processed. Is there something wrong with the configuration or is there any way to debug what is the cause for the messages not getting deleted

```
<int:chain input-channel="delayerChannel"
output-channel="checkMessageInProgress">
<int:header-enricher>
<!-- Exception/ERROR handling for flows originating from Delayer -->
    <int:header name="errorChannel" value="exceptionChannel"
        overwrite="true" />
    <int:header name="retryCount" overwrite="true" type="int"
        expression="headers['retryCount'] == null ? 0 : headers['retryCount'] + 1" />
</int:header-enricher>
<!-- If retryCount maxed out -discard message and log it in error table -->
<int:filter expression="(headers['retryCount'] lt 3)"
    discard-channel="raiseExceptionChannel">
</int:filter>
<!-- Configurable delay - fetch from property file -->
<int:delayer id="Delayer" default-delay="${timeout}"
    message-store="mymessageStore">

</int:delayer>
```

Comment: What is the Spring Integration version you use? Try to switch on `org.springframework.integration` and `org.springframework.jdbc` logging level to `debug` to observe what's going on after successful release of delayed messages. BTW do you see no one message is deleted from the table?

Comment: I am using Spring Integration 4.3.1.RELEASE. I am observing this issue only with few messages. I will enable the logs and will check

Comment: I am observing this issue in one of the environments where incoming messages are huge and I do not see this issue in another environment where the incoming messages are comparatively less in number.  I see some  old messages from past 4-5 days present in the Message table

Comment: Are you sure that those messages are processed good, too? Well, you should also keep in mind that not only delayer stores messages in that table. There are some other components with state, e.g. An aggregator

Comment: Delayer is the only component in my app where I am using a persistent message store. For other components like aggregator  I haven't defined any message store. So, I believe  in- memory message  store is used for such components

Comment: Yeah... would be great to play with such a behavior... may you form some minimal application to let us reproduce the problem locally?